# Stuck in understanding following macro definition

Tags: c++, macros

Here is a macro definition:

```
#define print_debug(fmt, ...) \
            __print_debug__(__FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, fmt, ## __VA_ARGS__)
```

I cannot locate the expansion of `__FILE__`,`__func__` ,`__LINE__` and `## __VA_ARGS__` in visual studio(I can get `__VA_ARGS__` that corresponds to a variable arguments). In particular what dose `## __VA_ARGS__` mean?

Comment: I believe it's an extension to ignore last comma if there is no argument

Comment: Why not reading the docs first? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__print_debug__` is a function like macro which will print all arguments passed to it.
Here

1. `__FILE__` :--> will pass current File name
2. `__func__`:--> will pass current function name.
3. `__LINE__` :--> will pass current line number

You can have a look at [This Link for more information on it.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html)
Now `fmt` and `## __VA_ARGS__` :

Let me take below example.

```
print_debug(fmt,var1,var2,var3)
```

the macro expansion will be as following:

```
__print_debug__(__FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, fmt,var1,var2,var3)
```

This is because `##` will concatenate all the the variable list of argument i.e. `__VA_ARGS__`

Save following code in macro.c file and compile it with

```
gcc -E macro.c -o macro.i
```

command and have a look at the macro.i file.

```
 #define print_debug(fmt, ...) \
     __print_debug__(__FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, fmt, ## __VA_ARGS__)

 void call_Macro()
 { 
     print_debug(2,3,4,5)  //Here 2 is nothing but fmt
 }

 int main()
 {
     call_Macro();
     return 0; #
 }
```